# Find the minimum amount of swaps in fixed indices to sort an array

Tags: algorithms, sorting

When given the length of a source array, I want to generate the array of swaps that need to be performed in order to sort the source array. I want to make this array **as small as possible**. Swaps will be performed only if necessary for sorting, as defined by the following function.

```
def compare_swap(array, a, b): 
    if array[a] < array[b]: 
      (array[a], array[b]) = (array[b], array[a])
```

Example

- input: **3**
- Output: **[(0,1), (1,2), (0,1)]**

What I mean is something like [network sorting](http://pages.ripco.net/~jgamble/nw.html).

I want to understand how to calculate the number of such swaps and how to generate such array exactly.

Comment: Your title makes sense, but your example is very confusing. Given an array, do you want to compute the minimum number of swaps to make the input array sorted?

Comment: @Juho Given array length, I want to calculate the minimum amount of swaps to sort array with that length. Also I want to output this data. For that I use array of pairs of indexes that each pair represent a swap. In my example I output such array for input 3, for source array with length of 3.

Comment: @Juho I want to find constant $l$ for any given array.

Comment: @Juho I define swap as the next method: >>> def compare_swap(array, a, b):
...     if array[a] < array[b]:
...         (array[a], array[b]) = (array[b], array[a])

Comment: related: [Minimum number of swaps needed to change Array 1 to Array 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2987605/4279)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question appears to be about [sorting networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network). Sorting an array in the comparison model requires $\Omega(n\log n)$ comparisons, and so $\Omega(n\log n)$ of your *swaps*. Ajtai, Komlós and Szemerédi were the first to come up with a matching $O(n\log n)$ sorting network (the AKS sorting network), and their construction was simplified by Patterson. These networks also have the advantage that they can be divided into $O(\log n)$ layers of disjoint swaps. Very recently, Goodrich came up with [Zigzag sort](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.2777), another $O(n\log n)$ sorting network.

Since we know that there exist $O(n\log n)$ sorting networks, we can find an optimal sorting network in time $\binom{n}{2}^{O(n\log n)} = 2^{O(n\log^2 n)}$ (verifying that a network works takes time roughly $2^n$ using the zero-one principle). There is no reason to expect any subexponential algorithm.

You might be interested in Ian Parberry's [page on sorting](http://larc.unt.edu/ian/research/sortingnetworks/).

---

This part answers the following question: What is the maximal number of swaps needed to order an array of length $n$?

Suppose that your array contained numbers from $1$ to $n$. Then you can think of it as a permutation $\pi \in S_n$. Swapping two elements in the same as multiplying by a transposition, so the question is how many transpositions we need to multiply to get $\pi$. If the cycle structure of $\pi$ is $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ then this number is $(a_1-1) + \cdots + (a_k-1) = n - k$. Therefore $n-1$ is the most that is needed. An example of a permutation needing $n-1$ swaps is $(234\cdots n1)$, which corresponds to the array $2,3,4,\ldots,n,1$.

Comment: It sound a bit strange as you are saying that I can sort any array with $(n - 1)$ swaps. Or am I missing some thing?

Comment: It seems I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: https://larc.unt.edu/ian/research/sortingnetworks/ gives 404 archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20110816183340/https://larc.unt.edu/ian/research/sortingnetworks/

Answer (score 0):

A swap array that will work for any list is $[01, 12, \ldots, (n-1)n, 01, 12, \ldots, (n-2)(n-1), \ldots, 01, 12, 01]$. So compare each subsequent pair of elements: this fixes the last element. Then compare each pair excluding the last element: this fixes the second to last element. In all there are $nC2$ comparisons. Your example fits this algorithm for $n=3$.

Edit: however I think this is not minimal

Comment: For input $n = 4$: output is: [0,1 , 2,3 , 1,3 , 0,2 , 1,2]

Comment: Well my algorithm would suggest [01, 12, 23, 01, 12, 01]. But I think now my solution is not minimal. The output you suggest looks like the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903086/standard-sorting-networks-for-small-values-of-n . That answer also has solutions with 9 swaps for a 5 element array. I haven't seen the algorithm it uses (and my viewing abilities are limited, I'm on a mobile) so I'm not sure of they are similar to what I've written here (my output uses one additional swap in the 4 and 5 element case)

Comment: (And off by 3 in the 6 element case)